# Prometheus query for Kubernetes pod uptime

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring

I have a Kubernetes cluster with an install of [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) (Prometheus 2.27.1, kube-state-metrics v2.0.0)

I would like to have a query to return how much time each pod was running, over last 24 hours

- If a pod is still running, the time from its creation to now
- If a post has terminated, the time from creation to completion

Importantly, I need exactly the time the pod existed, as opposed to CPU usage.

I can do something like this with:

```
kube_pod_completion_time - kube_pod_created
```

but it returns nothing for pods that are still running. And, since Prometheus does not return metrics that are more than 5 min old, it will not report anything for pods that were terminated and deleted.

How would I query Prometheus without these issues?

Comment: Which prometheus version is used? How was it deployed? (just to have a clear understanding about exact setup and available metrics)

Comment: I have added the setup details, thanks.

Comment: @VladimirPrus Thank you for response. Two more questions: which kubernetes version is used/how it was setup (cloud or on-premise)? And if you query only `kube_pod_completion_time`, do you see response/results? I installed a fresh `prometheus` and it doesn't return anything to me.

Comment: I use Kubernetes 1.19 using AWS EKS. And yes, kube_pod_completion_time returns results. Anyway, a colleague has provided a solution, so I'll update the question with it in a moment.

Answer (score 6):

One working solution is this:

```
sum by(namespace, pod) (

   (last_over_time(kube_pod_completion_time[1d]) 
   - last_over_time(kube_pod_created[1d])) 

  or 

    (time() - kube_pod_created)

)
```

The first part inside `sum` handles the case of pods that have terminated. We pick the last value of `kube_pod_completion_time` and `kube_pod_stared` and compute the difference.

The second part handles the pods that are still running. In that case, there is a fresh value of the `kube_pod_created` metric, and we can subtract it from the current time.

Comment: Hi  Vladimir do you know why kube_pod_completion_time is returning an empty result ? also  with kube_pod_created  I get wrong creation date like 2076 3 .... Any hint is more than welcome